# How to make the webbrowser address bar uneditable?

Tags: android

I want to open web browser with parameters in the url :

```
ConfigDb cfgDb = (new ConfigDb(getApplicationContext())).open();
String cfg_number = ConfigDb.getPhoneNumber(getApplicationContext());
Config cfg_url = cfgDb.getConfig("cfg.url");
String formul = "vidy;"+vokatraCode+";m="+tsenaCode+";l=mg;p=prepaid";
String url = cfg_url.getConfigValue()+"?from="+cfg_number+"&to=432&text="+formul;
cfgDb.close();
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

As we can see there is a security issue : after the webbrowser is opened then the user can edit the parameters values in the address bar. So how to make the address bar uneditable ? Or how to make users unable to edit the url in the address bar ?

Comment: how about hiding it ?

Comment: How to hide the url in the address bar ?

Comment: I mean using an in-app web view without an address bar. Is it applicable in your case?

Comment: Does webview write historic like with webbrowsers ?

Comment: Do you mean retain browsing history ?

Comment: yes , does webview retain history data ?

Comment: Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebHistoryItem.html)

Comment: If the data is sensitive then it should not be set as a query string especially if you're not using SSL.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling to browser application of phone instead of that you can create webView.

There is no way to hide address bar of native browser application because  the browser will not be modified by your manifest file or any other way, as it is an independent application

Please try adding this `WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Comment: Just after you create Webview object

Comment: Hey Man, Here in your code you are call native browser application, Try using webView.